# Default Error Handling in ReactiveCocoa - Best Design Pattern?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa, frp

I am working with [`AFNetworking+RACExtensions`](https://github.com/CodaFi/AFNetworking-RACExtensions) and ReactiveCocoa. My custom subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager` provides an implementation like this:

```
override func rac_GET(path: String!, parameters: AnyObject!) -> RACSignal {
    return super.rac_GET(path, parameters: parameters).doError { (error) in
        self.handle(error)
        // Shows an error banner and etc.
    }
}
```

Now my other API methods call this `rac_GET` like this:

```
APIManager.sharedInstance.rac_POST("news_feed", parameters: nil).doError { (error) in
            // ignore if HTTP response code is 406,
            // otherwise throw this error to default handler
            revertLocal()
        }
```

The intended effect is for the caller of the API `GET` method to handle HTTP errors first, possibly by handling some specific status codes, and if the error remains uncaught, it is passed to `rac_GET`'s default error handler and in this case displays an error banner.

The problem is that the `doError` block in `rac_GET` always runs *before* that in the caller method, thereby `rac_GET` always catches the errors, regardless of whether the callee handles it or not.

I want to find a way for a caller method of `rac_GET` to provide a custom error handler before the error is handled by the default block in `rac_GET`. I can achieve this by explicitly passing in a block like:

```
func rac_GET(path: String!, parameters: AnyObject!, errorHandler: ((NSError?) -> Void)?) -> RACSignal
```

But I'd like to see if there is a way to maintain the succinctness of RAC codes, possibly by a combination of `doError`, `catch`, `throw`, etc.

Thanks!